# how can i pass combox value to sql statement

Tags: vb6

I am creating a project in vb6.0 my form name is dariissue and combox name is combo1.
I want to pass selected value of combo1 in a sql statement. I want to match this combobox value with contractor field entry of dariissue table. I want to show the report for resultant record set. I am using data environment->command1->properties tag to write sql query. I am using following query

```
select * from dariissue where contractor like forms!dariissue!combo1
```

but it shows blank report.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the combobox's list value, or its itemData value (if you put anything in that).

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/visual-basic-combo-box-tutorial

has a good example - look at the Click event section.  Just 'combo1' will reference the control itself, not the selected value.